# Learning C #define statement (MACROS)

Tags: c, macros

I'm currently reading 'Programming in C' by Stephen G. Kochan, and I stumbled upon an exercise (Chapter 13, Ex 5):

> Write a macro `SHIFT` to perform the identical purpose as the `shift` function of Program **12.3**.

Here is program **12.3**:

```
unsigned int shift (unsigned int  value, int  n)
{
    if ( n > 0 )     // left shift 
        value <<= n;
    else             // right shift 
        value >>= -n;

    return value;
}
```

And here is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SHIFT(n)  (n) > 0 ? << (n) : >> (-(n))

unsigned int w1 = 0177777u, w2 = 0444u;
printf ("%o\t%o\n" w1 SHIFT(5), w1 << 5);
```

The condition in the macro should left shift if `n` is positive, and right shift otherwise.

Thus both arguments to `printf` should have the same value, but I keep getting a compiler error.

If I change the `#define` to:

```
#define SHIFT(n)  << n
```

... the code works, but I can't right shift with negative signs.

What is wrong with the conditional version of `SHIFT`?

Comment: I stated it is an exercise, please refer to text before adding answers

Comment: Before you do anything else, you need to check out the basics of how to write a function-like macro. This is probably addressed in the book. 1) every macro parameter, when used inside the function-like macro, must be surrounded by parenthesis `(n)`. 2) the whole macro must be surrounded by parenthesis. This is to avoid operator precedence bugs.

Comment: Read the text of the exercise. _Write a macro to performs the identical purpose as the shift **function**..._.  Your test code should be this: `printf ("%o\t%o\n", SHIFT(w1 ,5), shift(w1, 5);` and the macro should be something like `SHIFT(value, n) ...`. `shift` being the function of program 12.3.

Comment: I misread your question, and thought that this implementation of `SHIFT` was provided by the book. I have made a large edit to bring in more context -- feel free to rollback and/or tweak if it doesn't suit you :)

Comment: @Quentin Thanks a lot

Comment: Did the book tell you to shift with a negative right operand? Because that's a fat bug, you can't shift like that. If the book told you to do so, you need to burn the book ASAP.

Comment: @AjaoJumat _but even with the parenthèses_ please explain...

Comment: @Lundin `n` is correctly negated to get a positive shift amount each time.

Comment: @Lundin but even with the parentheses, It doesn't work

Comment: If you enter 0 it will right-shift `-0`. This is undefined behavior in theory.

Comment: @AjaoJumat read my first comment. The `SHIFT` macro needs __2__ arguments, just as the `shift` function has __2__ arguments.

Comment: @Lundin ... on platforms where `-0` is different from `0`, and thus a negative number. Got it. That's subtle.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SHIFT(n)  (n) > 0 ? << (n) : >> (-(n))
// #define SHIFT(n)  << n

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  unsigned int w1 = 0177777u, w2 = 0444u;
  printf("%o\t%o\n", w1 SHIFT(5), w1 << 5);
}
```

With `#define SHIFT(n)  << n` your code works as expected because macros are just textual substitutions. So the compiler actually sees this:

```
  printf("%o\t%o\n", w1 << 5, w1 << 5);
```

instead of this:

```
  printf("%o\t%o\n", w1 SHIFT(5), w1 << 5);
```

But with `#define SHIFT(n)  (n) > 0 ? << (n) : >> (-(n))` the compiler sees this:

```
  printf("%o\t%o\n", w1 (5) > 0 ? << (5) : >> (-(5)), w1 << 5);
```

and this is syntaxically wrong and doesn't make any sense.

You need this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SHIFT(value, n)  ... left as an exercise....

unsigned int shift(unsigned int  value, int  n)
{
  if (n > 0)     // left shift 
    value <<= n;
  else             // right shift 
    value >>= -n;

  return value;
}    

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  unsigned int w1 = 0177777u, w2 = 0444u;
  printf("%o\t%o\n", SHIFT(w1, 5), shift(w1, 5));    // test case for positive shift value
  printf("%o\t%o\n", SHIFT(w1, -5), shift(w1, -5));  // test case for negative shift value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please note that this function in itself is artificial for the purpose of learning - you would never hide basic stuff like bit shifts behind a function or macro. Doing so would just make the program less readable.

Step one is to fix the function so that it handles the case where `n` is zero.  Mainly we don't want to risk the compiler going haywire when presented with the expression `value >> -0`. (Less importantly, this also gives portability to exotic/fictional one's complement and sign & magnitude systems.)

```
inline unsigned int shift (unsigned int value, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)           // don't shift
        ;
    else if ( n > 0 )     // left shift 
        value <<= n;
    else /* n < 0 */      // right shift 
        value >>= -n;

    return value;
}
```

(`inline` is a micro-optimization hint to the compiler not to generate any overhead function-call code. Probably not needed on modern compilers.)

Then simply implement the macro just like the function. In any function-like macro, you need to use parenthesis around every macro parameter as well as the macro itself.

Since macros don't have return statement you have to ensure that it always evaluates to the desired value. This will in require that we use the conditional operator instead of if-else. Since `?:` doesn't give the option of `if - else if - else`, this will have to be a nested `?:` expression.

```
#define SHIFT(value, n) ( (n)==0 ? (value) :                  \
                                   ((n)>0 ? (value) <<= (n) : \
                                            (value) >>= -(n)) )
```

This would be one of the main reasons to avoid function-like macros. Instead of a clear, readable function, we have this nearly unreadable mess. Crappy programmers might even get tempted to write it as a horrible single line:

```
#define SHIFT(value, n) ((n)==0?(value):((n)>0?(value)<<=(n):(value)>>=-(n))) // BAD CODE
```

Comment: Just for curiosity: If we had a one's complement machine - wouldn't `0 == -0` still result in true?

Comment: @Aconcagua No it wouldn't. But that's not really worth pondering since the only one's complement computers that ever existed were some experimental ones back in the 70s and 80s. What's possibly a danger on modern computers, is that the C standard says (6.5.7) "If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.". Meaning that a compiler might decide to go haywire if presented with `-0` as the right operand. If this actually happens on some compiler in practice, I have no idea.

Comment: Hm, 0 is neither negative nor positive, thus must be -0, too, as (mathematically at least, and with two's complement, indeed) the same value. If `0 != -0` can be true on one's complement, I cannot imagine any more how one could do math with such a machine... Still, `value << 0` should be fine in any case (1-2 c, sm), so wouln't `if(n >= 0)` have been the more elegant fix for?

Comment: Oh, by the way if not pondering for such machines, why then bother for `value >> -0` at all? Don't you now contradict yourself?

Comment: @Aconcagua That's pretty deep down in the language-lawyer sewer. I would imagine it depends on pre-processing and order of evaluation of the expression. It may be that `-0` is guaranteed to be evaluated before the rest of the expression, in which case it shouldn't be an issue (on two's compl machines).

Comment: I personally woud upvote your answer just for the very first sencence alone already. What prevents me from is the introduction of an (in my eyes) absolutely unnecessary additional if. On 2-c machines, there shouldn't be any issue at all, on 1-c machines, provided that `-0 != 0` actually applies (which I cannot imagine at all...), then `-0 < 0` should apply as well and with  `if(n >= 0)` (>= instead of >) we'd get `value << 0` and `value >> -(-0)` respectively for both 0 representations...

Comment: @Aconcagua -0 != 0 applies without doubt on one's complement and sign & magnitude computers. The standard explicitly states that such implementations will have either negative zero or padding bits, then in detail describes how such things can lead to trap representations. The standard has gone to the extreme to cover these kind of systems. You must realize that the mathematical definition of things has no relevance here: in math, there is no such things as sign bits, padding bits, trap representations etc.

Comment: It all boils down to - if you aren't sure how a compiler will treat your code, then don't gamble. Feel free to raise a new question on SO regarding if `value << -0` will invoke UB or not.

Comment: As `-0 != 0` applies, with `n == -0`, `if(n >= 0)` will fail, so we get into the else block - where we calculate `value >> -(-0)` and we will be fine...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#define SHIFT(n) ((n) > 0 ? << (n) : >> (-(n)))
```